# How to make firebase deployer detect socket.io module folder and deploy firebase app with socket.io functions?

Tags: firebase, socket.io, google-cloud-functions

I have the following code in a index.js file with which I make the functions:

```
exports.run=require('firebase-functions').https.onRequest((req,res)=>{res.send("Firebase Working!")})
```

But the problem is that when I try to run this code:

```
net=(req,res)=>{res.send("Firebase Working!")}
exports.run=require('firebase-functions').https.onRequest(net)
require('socket.io').listen(net).on("connection",function(socket){})
```

... having the following module folders in google firebase:

socket.io

socket.io-adapter

socket.io-client

socket.io-parser

But when I run `\gfp>firebase deploy`, the console give me this error:

> Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'socket.io'
>
> Try running "npm install" in your functions directory before deploying.

After that, I runned `\gfp>npm install`, `\gfp>npm install socket.io`, `\gfp>npm install -g socket.io`, and finally, `\gfp>firebase deploy`. But the console give me this error again:

> Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'socket.io'
>
> Try running "npm install" in your functions directory before deploying.

How could I do for deploying the app with socket.io code and making a socket.io app in google firebase? Or it's impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include a node package in your functions deployment, install them like this:

```
npm install --save [package]
```

Then you can check to see if it appears in your package.json.  If it doesn't appear in package.json, it's not going to get deployed with the rest of your code.